# Independent stack navigation outside tab and drawer navigation in React-Native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack, react-navigation-drawer, react-navigation-bottom-tab

I use

- react-native:0.68.2
- react-navigation/bottom-tabs:6.3.1
- react-navigation/drawer:6.4.1
- react-navigation/native:6.0.10
- react-navigation/stack:6.2.1

And I have next navigation structure:

```
<Drawer.Navigator>
   <Tab.Navigator>
      <Stack.Navigator>
         <Screen1>
         <Screen2>
      </Stack.Navigator>
   </Tab.Navigator>
</Drawer.Navigator>
```

It looks like drawer slide menu from left side and bottom tabs on the main screen. You can see short video of it by next [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FOsJzHopKoHfH3K-NE1yBo1PgXxFyTKI/view?usp=sharing)

**What do I want**

I want to open new screen from Screen1 like independent screen (without tabs and drawer). It looks like new Activity in Android or new view controller in iOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to try this

```
const TabStack = () => {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
      initialRouteName="LiveRate"
      screenOptions={{
        tabBarActiveBackgroundColor: colors.activeTabColor,
        tabBarInactiveBackgroundColor: colors.inactiveTabColor,
        tabBarStyle: {
          backgroundColor: '#f46023',
          height:60
        },
      }}>
      <Tab.Screen
        name="LiveRate"
        component={LiveRateScreen}
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: () => {
            return (<Text style={{color:'white', fontSize:12, marginBottom:5}}>Live Rate</Text>)
          },
          headerShown: false,
            tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
                <Image
                    source={
                    focused
                        ? Images.liverate
                        : Images.liverate
                    }
                    style={{
                        width: 30,
                        height: 30,
                        resizeMode:'contain'
                        // padding:5
                    }}
                />
            ),
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="AboutUs"
        component={AboutUsScreen}
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: () => {
            return (<Text style={{color:'white', fontSize:12, marginBottom:5}}>About Us</Text>)
          },
          headerShown: false,
          tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color, size }) => (
            <Image
                source={
                focused
                    ? Images.aboutus
                    : Images.aboutus
                }
                style={{
                  width: 30,
                  height: 30,
                  resizeMode:'contain'
                    // padding:5
                }}
            />
        ),
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="booking"
        component={BookingNumberScreen}
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: () => {
            return (<Text style={{color:'white', fontSize:12, marginBottom:5}}>Booking Number</Text>)
          },
          headerShown: false,
          tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color, size }) => (
            <Image
                source={
                focused
                    ? Images.booking
                    : Images.booking
                }
                style={{
                  width: 30,
                  height: 30,
                  resizeMode:'contain'
                }}
            />
        ),
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="notification"
        component={NotificationScreen}
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: () => {
            return (<Text style={{color:'white', fontSize:12, marginBottom:5}}>Notification</Text>)
          },
          headerShown: false,
          tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color, size }) => (
            <Image
                source={
                focused
                    ? Images.notificationbell
                    : Images.notificationbell
                }
                style={{
                  width: 30,
                  height: 30,
                  resizeMode:'contain'
                }}
            />
        ),
        }}
      />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
};

const NavigationUtil = () => {

  return (
    <NavigationContainer  ref={navigationRef}>
          <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="SlpashScreen">
            <Stack.Screen
              name="tabStack"
              component={TabStack}  <----- you also pass your drawer stack
              options={{headerShown: false}}
            />
            <Stack.Screen
              name="Registration"
              component={RegistrationScreen}
              options={{headerShown: false}}
            />
            <Stack.Screen
              name="SlpashScreen"
              component={SlpashScreen}
              options={{headerShown: false}}
            />
          </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
 );
};
```

this is my code
hop it's working

Comment: Thank you. It works. I didn't even think that I can put more then one stack navigation in NavigationContainer. I will mark your answer as right. More information I have found in [documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators/#nesting-multiple-navigators)